# Best way to change a CSS transform property to a top property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, skrollr

I am using a Javascript plugin called Skrollr to change the position of elements on my page as you scroll down. The problem I'm running in to is that when I change the `top` position my elements get really jittery in Safari and Firefox but work great in IE 8. If I switch over to `transform:translate(x,y)` then it works great in everything but IE 8 where `transform` obviously is not supported. What I'm thinking about doing is having my Skrollr attributes switch over to `top` when somebody is using IE8.

Basically I want to change this...

```
<div class="example" data-0="transform:translate(0%, 100%);" data-700="transform:translate(0%, 0%);">
```

to this..

```
<div class="holder" data-0="top:100%;" data-700="top:0%;">
```

Is there a way I can change those properties with javascript/jquery? Or is there some other direction I should take that might be better? I attempted to do this with IE conditional comments but it was a giant mess and it didn't work in browsers other than IE8 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (/* is IE8 */) {
   $('div[data\-0^=transform]').attr('data-0', 'top:100%;');
}
```

Needs to run before the plugin obviously.